# "Intermediate Consistency" transaction fail

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlite

Hi all PostgreSQL / MySQL / SQLite experts and thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Consider the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE T (Col1 INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1), (2);

UPDATE T SET Col1 = Col1 + 1;
```

Executing it in either PostgreSQL, MySQL, or SQLite results in a primary key violation error.

However, the following code succeeds:

```
CREATE TABLE T (Col1 INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1), (2);

UPDATE T SET Col1 = Col1 - 1;
```

Oracle and SQL Server behave as expected, and the same (equivalent for Oracle) scripts succeed and commit with no errors as they should IMHO.

It seems that the success or failure of the transaction for PostgreSQL, MySQL, and SQLite depend on some physical update order, and constraints are checked per row, before the update completes.
This violates the fundamental "All at once" principle as I understand it.

This doesn't make any sense to me. What am I missing?

Stay safe and healthy!

Comment: Regarding Postgres, there is a good review of deferrable constraints here: https://begriffs.com/posts/2017-08-27-deferrable-sql-constraints.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question, and this is more of an extended comment.

I think you are correct in your understanding of ACID properties -- either the entire transaction is committed or none of it.  And, if the data is valid at the end of the transaction, it should match.

I'm not 100% sure that this is specified in the standard.  In any case, constraints are likely to have a bit of leeway in the standard in terms of whether they are implemented "per row", "per statement", or "per transaction".  Actually, the last seems quite unlikely.

As you have noted, different databases handle this differently.  I will note that my recommendation for solving this typically involves two updates:

```
update t
    set col1 = - col1;

update t
    set col1 = (- col1) + 1;
```

This is more expensive, but given that numbers used as keys are almost never negative, this usually works.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts Gordon. I understand there may be workarounds. My question is more on the theoretical aspect. The article that Mike e. shared in his comment to my post is helpful as well, and provides schema-level workaround by defining "deferred constraints". It's amazing that after 25 years of SQL, I still learn something new almost every week...

Answer (score 0):

There is no "all at once" principle in SQL as far as I know.

There is the "all or nothing" that is the atomicity required for transactions, but that is something different.

Comment: "SQL is a declarative language, so a statement takes effect all at once, not in sequential steps" - Joe Celko, Joe Celko's Analytics and OLAP in SQL, Chapter 5 Page 52. Joe Celko participated on the ANSI X3H2 Database Standards Committee, and helped write the SQL-89 and SQL-92 standards so I think his authority is not in doubt.

Comment: Note that it says "takes effect", not "is executed". So you will see the change only when the complete statement is done.